# Can't mount flash drive

Tags: linux, qnx, usb-flash-drive

Is there somebody who knows how to mount usb flash drive in QNX Neutrino OS properly?
I have two versions of QNX, the first version is installed on VMWare virtual machine and second is installed on other PC(this image OS I have assembled myself).

When I connect usb flash to the first, it is mount properly and automatically at /fs/usb0, there is sloginfo output:

```
Oct 22 10:12:58    2    19   900 devb-umass 1.00A (Jun 20 2012 13:41:13)
Oct 22 10:12:58    2     5     0 libcam.so (Jun 20 2012 13:40:15) bver 6050001
Oct 22 10:12:58    2     5   100 cam-disk.so (Jun 20 2012 13:40:19)
```

In my own assembled QNX, I'm trying to connect flash in next way:

```
io-usb -dohci -dehci -duhci
```

then I check the output of USB utility:

```
USB 1 (EHCI) v1.10, v1.01 DDK, v1.01 HCD

Device Address             : 1
Vendor                     : 0x0951 (Kingston)
Product                    : 0x1665 (DataTraveler 2.0)
Class                      : 0x00 (Independent per interface)
```

after that, I'm trying:

```
devb-umass cam pnp umass vid=0x0951,did=0x1665,devno=1
```

I suppose, I have made mistake somewhere, because usb flash is not appeared as /fs/usb0

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: This Q/A site is for programming related questions only, infernalcucumber. Try superuser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I suppose I have found the solution:

I've seen, that usb flash drive is appeared at /dev as hd1t11, where 11 is type of OS, in my case it is FAT32.

I've connected it next way:

```
devb-umass cam pnp
mount -tdos /dev/hd1t11 /mnt/usb/
```